# Filtering data Excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have an EXCEL table with 4000+ rows of passport data. All data is written in one column. I need to filter this data by certain criteria and split it into separate columns. I tried to use the EPPlus library(using C#), but still am not quite sure how to do it. Unfortunately, I haven't found optimal solutions for my problem on the Internet.

Сan anyone please tell me which direction to go? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: One-column file can be saved to a txt file, then you can work with it using the C# techniques from any textbook.

Comment: Yes,exactly. Thank you for the advice. I will try